# Opera directory at "/usr/lib" is missing

Tags: 14.04, flash, opera

I just installed Opera, just to give it a shot. I encountered the usual inconvenience with Flash Player.

According to Opera documentation, I need to download the tar file from Adobe, then extract it and copy to the Opera Plugins Directory. Such directory is missing.

There is one inside of /`usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Opera`, but there is no plugin directory inside.

Firstly I installed opera from the public repositories, in the end it was an old version which the browser itself suggested to update to `Opera 27` through a `.deb` file. I did.

After that I'm trying to locate the directory to install flash. Several sources tell how to install older versions, even a developer version which I'm not interested to install. But they all seem to have the `/usr/lib/opera/plugins/` Directory, which mine is somehow, missing.

Comment: The Opera documentation is for older versions of Opera that are based on the Presto engine. Newer versions use the Blink engine. Webupd8 have a tutorial for enabling the Pepper Flash plugin in Opera, it's for version 26 but should also work for the version 27 you have installed. http://www.webupd8.org/2014/12/how-to-get-flash-and-h264-to-work-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Restart Opera.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for 12.04??

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if flash player is properly installed:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
```

In new Opera from 15 version the only most appropriate way to flash player work is using **PPAPI** flash player interface supported by default in **multiverse** repository in Ubuntu, not adobe-flashplugin, full description how to do that [is here](http://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=152&t=180008).
All advises found in Opera sites are obsolete and leads to misunderstandings, and not only in opera sites. Now the only correct way to use newest flash player in Opera and I think all browsers based on derivative of webkit engine is **PPAPI**.

Answer (score 0):

Only installing `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` did not help.
What I did, Using Kubuntu 16.04 and Opera 40 (40.0.2308.62):

1. You need to install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` just like explained above
2. Afterwards you also need to tell opera where to find the plugin, since `opera` doesnt work with `/usr/lib/` directory anymore. However i found out that the directory should be `/opt/google/chrome`. So you should copy and paste `libpepflashplayer.so` in this directory.
   The `libpepflashplayer.so` file was in the directory : `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/`

You can do:

```
    sudo cp  /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so  /opt/google/chrome
```

Now if you restart opera, in the plugins tab you can see your adobe flashplayer plugin and it should work.